# Error:"directory does not exist" despite creation [writing CSV to a directory]

Tags: csv, stored-procedures, plsql, directory, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to replicate the Custom Solution (PL/SQL) steps shown in the link below, except with the sample HR schema from SQL Developer:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/generating-csv-files

here is my version of the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY EXTRACT_DIR AS 'C:\Users\Jimbo\Desktop\delete';
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY EXTRACT_DIR TO PUBLIC;
--select * from dba_users;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EMP_CSV AS
    CURSOR c_data IS
        SELECT FIRST_NAME,
               LAST_NAME
        FROM   HR.EMPLOYEES
        ORDER BY last_name;

    v_file  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
    v_file := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(location     => 'EXTRACT_DIR',
                             filename     => 'emp_csv.txt',
                             open_mode    => 'w',
                             max_linesize => 32767);

    FOR cur_rec IN c_data LOOP
        UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_file, cur_rec.first_name||cur_rec.last_name);
    END LOOP;

    UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_file);
END;
/

EXEC EMP_CSV;
```

However, after running EXEC EMP_CSV, an error is returned:
"invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists."

Can someone tell me what I have to do for this to work?

Comment: Does the server where your Oracle instance is running have a folder named `C:\Users\Jimbo\Desktop\delete`? The path is related to the server's drive, not your local one.

Comment: I dont think it does... how can I access/view/edit server folders?.... or can I write to a local drive? I'd just like to write it somewhere as quickly and simply as possible.

Comment: I am running everything on my personal computer. I have no server that I'm aware of.

Comment: If you have an Oracle database, you have a server (even if it's your own local computer). Your Oracle instance is running on a server, most likely using a service account, and that service account has no knowledge of or access to your personal user directory. You'll need to write to a path where the server has write access; I can't tell you where that would be because you can't tell me where your server is running (and most likely can't say what account it's running under).

Comment: Thanks Ken, are there some sql commands that will provide me with the server information that I need?